# How can i change github webhook secret in openshift with cli

Tags: github, openshift

AS defined [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/triggering_builds.html),
i linked the secret that i created to webhook secret with web portal and changing the yaml file directly.like;

```
type: "GitHub"
github:
  secretReference:
    name: "mysecret"
```

Is there a way to do this over cli using oc?

Comment: Look at ``oc set triggers --from-github bc/yourbcname``. You will then have to query back what it was set to.

Comment: thx for comment @GrahamDumpleton however this command auto generate new implicit secret, it either doesnt link to an existing secret or create a user defined one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about you to use `oc patch` as follows ?

For instance, you want to update new secret as `mysecret` in test `buildconfig`.

```
oc patch bc/test \
-p '{"spec": {"triggers": [{"type": "GitHub","github": {"secretReference": {"name": "mysecret"}}}]}}'
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: Thx @Daein, i think this is the way that i looking for but it gives following error, do you have any idea? (i already valide json) "Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character 's' looking for beginning of object key string"

Comment: It looks like  typo is causing the message. As you know, “\” does not include in the command if you execute as one line.

Comment: Now it works. you should escape double quote by using \". it is problem for both linux and win powershell.  Related versions are  oc v3.11.0+0cbc58b  
kubernetes v1.11.0+d4cacc0   kubernetes v1.13.4+c62ce01. and command i used is  oc patch bc my-tw-app -p '{\"spec\": {\"triggers\": [{\"type\": \"GitHub\",\"github\": {\"secretReference\": {\"name\": \"github-webhook-secret\"}}}]}}'